# How to display selected installed applications in grid view

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-gridview

**I have this code to show the installed applications in Android. I also want to display the selected applications by the user in Grid view. How can I do that in this code?

And is there always a need for adapter for grid-view also?**

This is my first activity:

```
package com.abhi.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.applist.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Startup extends Activity {

    Button bIns, bSel;

    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        bIns = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bList);
        bSel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGrid);

    }

    public void viewList(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void viewGrid(View view) {

        myList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mySelectedList");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Last.class);
        intent.putExtra("mySelectedList",myList);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

This is my second activity:

```
package com.abhi.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.abhi.test.ApplicationAdapter;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.applist.R;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;
    Button button;
    Bundle bundle;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> selectedapplication = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        packageManager = getPackageManager();

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_app);

        new LoadApplications().execute();

        //Intent intent = new Intent(this,Last.class);

    }

    public void selectedApps(View view) {

        //new ApplicationAdapter().selApps();
        selectedapplication = ApplicationAdapter.finalList;
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Startup.class);
        intent.putExtra("mySelectedList",selectedapplication);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
        try {
            Intent intent = packageManager
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

            if (null != intent) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(
            List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName) != null) 
                {
                    applist.add(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return applist;
    }

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager
                    .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    R.layout.row, applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null,
                    "Loading application info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }
}
```

Array adapter for second activity:

```
package com.abhi.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.applist.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {
    private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
    private Context context;
    int position1;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    private PackageManager packageManager;
    public ArrayList<Boolean> checkList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    private OnCheckedChangeListener listener;


    public static ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> finalList = null;

    public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList);

        this.context = context;
        this.appsList = appsList;
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

         for (int i = 0; i < appsList.size(); i++) 
         {
             checkList.add(false);
         }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (appsList != null) {
            return appsList.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
        if (appsList != null) {
            return appsList.get(position);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override //ibuilt function getView()--responsinle for making views
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if ( view == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);         //Understand
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
        if (data != null) {
            TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage);
            ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
            position1=position;
            checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_app);       //understand
            checkBox.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position)); // set the tag so we can identify the correct row in the listener
            checkBox.setChecked(checkList.get(position)); // set the status as we stored it        
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mListener); // set the listener


            appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
            packageName.setText(data.packageName);
            iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));


           /* if(checkBox.isChecked())
            {
                finalList.add(data);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "App Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }*/
        }
        return view;
    }

    OnCheckedChangeListener mListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {   
          checkList.set((Integer)buttonView.getTag(),isChecked);    // get the tag so we know the row and store the status



         }
    };

}
```

This is the last activity in which I want to show the selected applications by the user:

```
package com.abhi.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.applist.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class Last extends Activity{

    GridView gridview;
    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> appList;
    String[] appName = new String[100];
    String[] appPack = new String[100];
    String[] appComp = new String[100];
    ArrayList<String> appInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.last);

        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        appList = (ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mylist");

        for(int i=0;i<appList.size();i++)
        {
            appName[i] = appList.get(i).name;
            appPack[i] = appList.get(i).packageName;
            appComp[i] = appName[i]+appPack[i];
            appInfo.add(appComp[i]);
        }



        /* ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo>(this,
                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, appInfo);

      gridview.setAdapter(adapter);*/
    }
}
```

XML for the first activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:onClick="viewList"
        android:text="@string/bInstalledApps" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/bGrid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:onClick="viewGrid"
        android:text="@string/bSelectedApps" />

</LinearLayout>
```

XML for the second activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:onClick="selectedApps"
        android:text="Done"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

row.xml for adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/appdata"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_app"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:scaleX="1.50"
        android:scaleY="1.50" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_paackage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

XML for the last activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A GridView is a collection of views in a grid. The Android system doesn't magically know what views you want to be in it. This is where the adapter comes in. By setting an adapter for a GridView, you tell the GridView several things about how you want it to display views including how many views there are and what each view looks like. So yes, all GridViews need adapters.